# RuntimeIdentifier must be included in csproj after upgrading to VS 2022 in order to publish, but how can I specify multiple identifiers?

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2022

I have a project which was publishing to a local folder without problems in VS 2019, until a hard drive failure a couple of days ago. Publish profiles were not committed to source control, and now after upgrading to VS 2022 I can no longer publish the same way  without running into the following error:

> It is not supported to publish an application to a single-file without specifying a RuntimeIdentifier. You must either specify a RuntimeIdentifier or set PublishSingleFile to false.

I added `<RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>` to my csproj file, and that fixes the problem, but I also need to be able to target a linux container.  Since this is not a build configuration setting I don't see how that's possible without creating different publish profiles.  I would guess that may be the best way forward, but something seems off about not being able to publish to a *portable* single-file without a targeted run-time environment.

I've also read that `RuntimeIdentifier` more or less informs nuget on which package versions to use.  I did have a problem setting up nuget while installing VS 2022 so I have to wonder if this is a nuget configuration problem?  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can see from [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog).

> Multiple RIDs can be defined as a semicolon-delimited list in the
> project file's RuntimeIdentifiers element. They're also used via the
> --runtime option with the following .NET CLI commands.

Hope it can help you.